Use chakra embossed a form, after submit, the form is Inoperable
1.the login.js: Open the pop-up window and set the content according to the submitted response result.
 useEffect(() => {
    if (response) {
      onOpen(response.type, response.message);
      if(response.type === 'success'){
        formik.resetForm();
      }
    }
}, [response]); 

2.alertContext.js: Define the context information needed to open the pop-up window in the context object.
 export const AlertProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isOpen: false,
    type: 'success',
    message: '',
  });
  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        onOpen: (type, message) => setState({ isOpen: true, type, message }),
        onClose: () => setState({ isOpen: false, type: '', message: '' }),
      }} 

3.Aler.js: Display pop-ups based on contextual information.
function Alert() {
    const { isOpen, type, message, onClose } = useAlertContext();
    const cancelRef = useRef();
    const isSuccess = type === "success"

    return (
      <AlertDialog
        isOpen={isOpen}
        leastDestructiveRef={cancelRef}
        onClose={onClose}
      >
        <AlertDialogOverlay >
          <AlertDialogContent py={4} backgroundColor={isSuccess ? '#F4CE14' : '#EE9972'}>
            <AlertDialogHeader fontSize="lg" fontWeight="bold">
              {isSuccess ? 'All good!' : 'Oops!'}
            </AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogBody>{message}</AlertDialogBody>

I don't know why, after clicking submit, the pop-up window appears, and then I click on the blank area. After the pop-up window disappears, the form elements cannot be operated, as if there is a transparent mask on it. At this time, I check the elements in the console and find that the  related to the alert still exists.
I hope that after the pop-up window disappears, the form will operate normally.When the pop-up window first appears, it will also be in this state. Although it has been rendered, the pop-up window cannot be seen.

oh! I think is because the version of  chakra and react  should match.
